# How to determine the value of passing arguments of a function via the backtrace of a process?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I have a backtrace of a process. and I want determine the value of a argument of one function called in the call trace, I have the .o file and I disassemble it, So I have the assembly procedure of that particular function, How can I calculate the value of the function's passing argument through the backtrace and the assembly code? It's on the ARM platform, I'm not quite familar with the ARM call trace, and assembly code.

Comment: Those arguments which your applicable ABI's calling convention says go on the stack will be present in the stack frames.  But those which go in registers - which on an ARM would traditionally be the first few - will not.  However, the actual implementation of functions (which is apparently available for you to examine) may sometimes save some register arguments on the stack if it needs to use those registers for something else, such as making a call of its own.

Comment: You might want to create an example program with known arguments (use 6 or so per call) and nest a few levels deep, so you can start to see how the theory actually looks.

Comment: Wow, first time to ask on stackoverflow, it's unbelievable, That's exactly what I'm talking about, it did save in the register first and then it goes to the stack frame, somehow it related to the SP, in ARM's stack, the called function address is current PC, so the current SP will be PC -8, is that correct?

Comment: Keep in mind that arm may keep the first return address in the LR, not on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is written in C, this information is not available solely from the executable image, for the simple reason that C does not mangle function name symbols in order to encode the function parameter types.

Brief experimentation with gdb shows that if C code is compiled with the debugging flag, `-g`, gcc does put sufficient information into the executable's debug records for gdb to be able to figure out the function parameter types, and display function arguments in the backtrace.

But, if the executable is not compiled with `-g`, all that's in the executable are the function names, and their addresses, and that's all that gdb can show, in a backtrace from a coredump.

So, if you're working with .o files containing C code, without any debug stuff in it, there's nothing that can show you what the function parameters are,

Comment: This is not the question which was asked.  The poster wants to know the value of the arguments, not their type.

Comment: To know their value, you have to know the type, first. Once the type is known, a debugger is capable of displaying it. It's going to be an amazing feat to be able to show a value of something, without knowing its type.

Comment: Untrue - you are trapped in high level language (Java or C++, not C) thinking which limits your awareness. Memory is dumped all the time without type information and the values shown are useful.  You do not have to know type to know value.  It may help in *interpreting* the value, but one can usually *infer* it anyway (non-null pointers tend to have different values than ints, non-word widths have clues, etc).  Usage (the machine code is available) also provides a clue.

Comment: Now, try to implement your ideas in code, and see how well it works. A human brain is certainly smart enough to figure out what it's looking at, by peeking and poking the bytes. But if you're looking for a magic button that will tell you what parameters are on the frame, and what they mean, without any other metadata, it's not going to be easy to find a magic button, like that.

Comment: Nothing in the question implies it is seeking an automated solution.  The idea that the debugger will do it for you comes from you, not the asker and is a lot of what I meant by high level language mindset.  For experienced developers *especially in the embedded field tagged here* we really don't need any type interpretation - a hex display of the value is fine.  That said, it would be easy to create something which displays a variety of possible type interpretations from which the human can pick  (and useful if ugly things like floats are plausible).

Comment: If someone is planning to eyeball the raw data, and figure out the parameter values that way, I'm puzzled as to what the actual question is. Just look at the raw data, and let the human brain figure it out. There's nothing left to ask, about. Perhaps the question here might be what kind of a data pattern indicates which kind of values and types.

Comment: The question is effectively *where* the values for arguments end up.